# Prove (or check) the expression is positive given constraints on variables?

Tags: proof-writing

The following proof problem have taken me a few days. Perhaps it is too hard for me to overcome it. Can you help me?

The expression is by the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&2\,x{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right) -{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right) +{c}^
{x}\ln  \left( c \right) +{c}^{x}{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right) -x{2}^{x
}\ln  \left( 2 \right) +2\,{x}^{2}{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right) -{c}^
{x}\ln  \left( c \right) {x}^{2}\\
&-{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) {2}^{x}+
2\,{c}^{x-1}+{2}^{x}-2\,{c}^{x}+{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) x{2}^{x}-
2\,x{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right) {2}^{x}-{c}^{x}x{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 
2 \right) \\
&+2\,x{c}^{x-1}{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right) +{c}^{x}{2}^{x}-2
\,{c}^{x-1}{2}^{x},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $x\in[2,+\infty)$, and $1<c<2$.

Our goal is to prove that the aforementioned expression is positive .

To facilitate subsequent view, I give each terms in the expression a unique sequence number by the following:

1. $\qquad$$2\,x{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right)$
2. $\qquad$$ -{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right)$
3. $\qquad$${c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right)$
4. $\qquad$${c}^{x}{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right)$
5. $\qquad$$-x{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right)$
6. $\qquad$$2\,{x}^{2}{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right)$
7. $\qquad$$-{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) {x}^{2}$
8. $\qquad$$-{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) {2}^{x}$
9. $\qquad$$2\,{c}^{x-1}$
10. $\qquad$${2}^{x}$
11. $\qquad$$-2\,{c}^{x}$
12. $\qquad$${c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) x{2}^{x}$
13. $\qquad$$-2\,x{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right) {2}^{x}$
14. $\qquad$$-{c}^{x}x{2}^{x}\ln  \left(2 \right)$
15. $\qquad$$2\,x{c}^{x-1}{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right)$
16. $\qquad$${c}^{x}{2}^{x}$
17. $\qquad$$-2\,{c}^{x-1}{2}^{x}$

Maybe the right way is $\cdots\quad$Try showing that each term  is $>0$. If some are $< 0$, try combining two or more. This will get you closer to the desired proof.

But HOW?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a **false proof**. However, the method may be right. So it still has certain reference significance.

Combine term $9$, $10$ and $11$, we get
$$
2\,{c}^{x-1}+{2}^{x}-2\,{c}^{x}=\left( \frac{2}{c}-1 \right) {c}^{x}+\left({2}^{x}-{c}^{x}\right)>0
$$;

Combine term $4$ and $8$, we get
$$
{c}^{x}{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right) -{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) {2}^{x}=c^x2^x\left(\ln(2)-\ln(c)\right)>0
$$;

Combine term $(12,14) + (13,15) $, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\,&\{{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) x{2}^{x}-{c}^{x}x{2}^{x}\ln  \left(2 \right)\}+\{-2\,x{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right) {2}^{x}+2\,x{c}^{x-1}{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right)\}\\
&=-c^xx2^x\left(\ln2-\ln c\right)+2xc^{x-1}2^x\left(\ln2-\ln c\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{2}{c}-1\right)2^xxc^x\left(\ln2-\ln c\right)>0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
;

Combine term $1,3,6,7$, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&2\,x{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right)+{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right)+2\,{x}^{2}{c}^{x-1}\ln  \left( c \right)-{c}^{x}\ln  \left( c \right) {x}^{2}\\
&=\left(\left(\frac{2}{c}-1\right)x^2+\frac{2}{c}x+1\right)\cdot c^x\ln c
\end{split}.
\end{equation}
As the equation
$$\left(\frac{2}{c}-1\right)x^2+\frac{2}{c}x+1=0$$ has two roots $-1$ and $-\frac{1}{\frac{2}{c}-1}$, which has the following inequality relation
$$-\frac{1}{\frac{2}{c}-1}<-1,$$
So we have $$\left(\frac{2}{c}-1\right)x^2+\frac{2}{c}x+1>0$$ 
for $1<c<2$ and $x>2$
.

At this point, four terms have not been considered, namely $ 2,5,16$ and $17$. One can easily deduce that **2+5 and 16+17 are both negative quantities**. 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\{-{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right) -x{2}^{x}\ln  \left( 2 \right)\} +\{{c}^{x}{
2}^{x}-2\,{c}^{x-1}{2}^{x}\}\\
&=(-1-x)2^x\ln 2 +(1-\frac{2}{c})c^x2^x<0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So something went wrong.

Comment: Another one is 4+8

Comment: Do (12+14) + (13+15) gives you another one

Comment: 1+3+6+7 gives another one

Comment: Did you figure out how to deal with 2,5,16,17 yet?

Comment: Lol that what's I thought, well one can easily deduce that 2+5 and 16+17 are both negative quantities, you just need to combine them with the right term to get the final result. By the way, are you sure this expression is positive (with the given constraint) ?

Comment: But with the given constraint, they are not positive. For example, $2+5$ is equal to $-2^x\ln(2) -x2^x\ln(2) = -2^x\ln(2)(x+1)<0$ since $x$ is positive.

Comment: I try to combine (16,17) and (4,8), but find that the four-term combinations  is negative for some c,x combinations.